# How to set up a test environment in Node JS to figure out what are run asynchronously or synchronously?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, synchronous

Let's say we have these operations to test:

- creating new instances of objects `var person = new Person();`
- setting a property of an object `person.name = 'aponxi';`
- any called method of an object `person.sayName();`
- requiring a js script. `var debug = require('debug');`
- Promises (bluebird) `Promise.all(array_of_promises).then(function(results){});`

How does one go about proving that they run synchronously or asynchronously?

- Do we look at stack trace? (I have WebStorm, is that capable of figuring the order of operation?)
- Are there utilities that are effective at finding the order (some npm package for unit testing? I ask this because let's say I'm interested in finding order of 3 things but when I look at the stack trace it would be cluttered with all the other things)
- Are `console.log()`s going to be unreliable?

Comment: Everything in node.js/JavaScript is synchronous. Things are just put on ice allowing other things to process. This is a very generalized expression though and there's alot more to how the event loop works

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: @vlaz I'm trying to figure out how to prove that the program runs in a certain way that I intend. How to set up debug logs that would tell us the order of operation / How to look at stack trace in node js in a filtered matter so that the ones I'm trying to find out about pop out.